# How can I automatically maintain reciprocal relationships?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table with entities that can have a 1:1 relationship. When a user updates one record, I'd like to automatically update the other, but database triggers won't allow me to do this because it's updating the same table as the triggering event. (MySql Error: Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger).

Schema for MyEntity
`{id: INT NOT NULL, ref_id: INT NULL}`

Sample user action:
`UPDATE MyEntity SET ref_id = 2 WHERE id = 1`

Desired automated action:
`UPDATE MyEntity SET ref_id = 1 WHERE id = 2`

I realize this can get more complicated if entity 2 happens to already have a non-null ref_id, but that can be left for later. Can this be done via trigger, or do I absolutely have to do it by changing the application code that is making the user call?

Comment: Use a separate stored procedure (and no triggers)? Or, change the schema?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query - but why not simply include the reciprocity in the update (or remove the redundancy altogether)

Comment: I am trying to avoid modifications to legacy code, if at all possible.